# Send postscript file to 4 tray of printer

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have code for sending ps file to printer but I need to sent ps file to tray 4. How can i do it ?

My code:

c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin>gsprint "c:\1\1.ps" -printer "RICOH Pro C5300SL"

Thanks mArek

Comment: You don't 'send ps file to tray 4' you need to direct the printer to use tray 4 to print the result of rendering the PostScript program. The usual method for doing that is to include a PostScript fragment which tells the interpreter which tray to print on. The first thing you will need to do is find out how to do that for your printer, because it is device-dependent (ie it is different for each printer). Then you will need to modify the PostScript program, without breaking it, by injecting that code into the correct point in the program.

Comment: Oh, and I see you see using gsprint, which will interpret the PostScript program and render it. There is no way, as far as I know, to tell gsprint which tray to use,so the only way to get that to work is to set up the defaults for your printer so that it prints to tray 4. Its possible this printer supports PostScript directly in which case you should send the PostScript program to it rather than using gsprint.